# UML sequence diagram: how do i draw cron job?

Tags: uml, use-case, sequence-diagram

I'm developing an application that takes advantages of restaurants' dataset. Each week my system will run a CRON job in order to synchronize the restaurants that are available on a public API to my database.

However, how do I draw the sequence diagram for this CRON job? Who is the actor?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The actor would be some scheduler (or you can use the Cron object if you like).  The target would be your `Synchronizer` object doing all that fancy web scanning.

[image]

You can use a `loop` fragment to show the repetition. A simple note would do as well :-)

Comment: if i were to generalize it, can the Scheduler actor be Web Server?

Comment: I thought `Scheduler` to be the most general form :-) Of course you can use a Web Server as actor but in your question you were talking of `cron` which is not a web server at all but some basic OS program.